# TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <f4 in io.imsave(fname,value)

Tags: database, environment-variables, format, handle, python-3.11

When I run this code in the vitrula environment:

```
names = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
]

values = [img, pert, diff]
for name, value in zip(names, values):
    if value is not None:
        fname = os.path.join(folder, name + ".jpg")
        io.imsave(fname, value)
        print ("{} image saved to {}".format(name, fname))
    else:
        print ("{} image not saved (None given)".format(name))
```

It has an error like this.
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <f4.

I found those errors in the function io.imsave(fname, value).
So how do I fix it?
Please, can anyone give me any ideals?

I tried fixing it by changing values and fname in the dtype = uint8 object. But it is not yet working.

Comment: Error in function io.imsave()